# Why "vsprintf" is getting stuck when calling a function from a macro using __VA_ARGS__?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I have the following macro:

```
#define TRACE__LOW(str, col, ...)\
        TR_Trace("\r\e[" COLOR(col) "%s :: %s():%d; LOW - " str "\e[0m\r\n",\
        ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

And the function **TR_Trace** looks like this:

```
void TR_Trace(const char *const string, ...)
{
   va_list aptr;
   size_t stringSize = 0;
   char tempString[250];

   va_start(aptr, string);
   vsprintf(tempString, string, aptr);
   va_end(aptr);
}
```

And I'm using it like this:

```
TRACE__LOW("Led[%d] toggled every %d milliseconds (%5d)", GREEN
            init_parameters.led, delay_time, counter++);
```

The problem here is that once the execution gets to **vsprintf(tempString, string, aptr);** it gets stuck there.

Do anybody know what is happening or if I'm not using correctly the **VA_ARGS**?

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting stuck"?  Also, did you mean to use `vprintf()` instead of `vsprintf()`?

Comment: You shouldn't use the `##` before `__VA_ARGS__`; you're not pasting it onto another string.  And what is `GREEN`, was it supposed to be `GREEN,` ? Otherwise I don't understand that line.

Comment: @MattMcNabb ##__VA_ARGS__ is known extension to get rid of `,` sign when __VA_ARGS__ is empty. It is actually correct (but non-standard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You adding `%s :: %s():%d;` to format string, but don't adding extra arguments to fill these patterns.

I suppose it meant to be

```
#define TRACE__LOW(str, col, ...)\
        TR_Trace("\r\e[" COLOR(col) "%s :: %s():%d; LOW - " str "\e[0m\r\n",\
        __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__,\
        ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

Comment: You are right! when I modified the macro to add the __VA_ARGS__ I erased the "__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__," parameters so that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Random thoughts:

Your use of `__VA_ARGS__` appears to be correct.

The `TRACE__LOW` macro adds a superfluous semi-colon to the output (could cause problems for conditional statements that don't have curly braces).

I don't know what `COLOR(GREEN)` expands to, so that may be the source of the problem.

Suggestion:

Your compiler should have an option to output the results from the preprocessor. On the compiler I'm using that option is -E. If you have the compiler output the results from the preprocessor, you can see precisely what your macro expands to.

For example, compiling the following code with -E

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRACE__LOW(str, col, ...)\
TR_Trace("\r\e[" COLOR(col) "%s :: %s():%d; LOW - " str "\e[0m\r\n",\
##__VA_ARGS__);

int main( void )
{
    TRACE__LOW( "test", 3, a, b, c );
}
```

produces this output (after about 5 million other lines ;) )

```
int main( void )
{
    TR_Trace("\r\e[" COLOR(3) "%s :: %s():%d; LOW - " "test" "\e[0m\r\n", a, b, c);;
}
```